# What will be the output of the following pseudo code for input 7?

Tags: python-2.7, pseudocode

Please help me to understand the following code and what will be the possiable output.

What will be the output of the following pseudo code for input 7?

1.Input n

2.Set m = 1, T = 0

3.if (m > n)

4. Go to step 9

5.else

6. T = T + m
7. m = m + 1

8.Go to step 3

9.Print T

Answer (score 0):

0

`n` is less than `n` so go to step 9 which is print `T` which is equal to 0 as set in step 2.

Answer (score 0):

T should be **28**. It will loop till m>7 (since n=7) and in each iteration T adds m to itself, since T is 0 initially it is only summing up m after incrementing it by 1 in each iteration.So if you add 1+2+3.....+7 you get 28 and that is when the loop breaks since m is now equal to 8.

Answer (score 0):

for m =  1 2 3 4  5  6  7 and for 8 m>n will be true and it will go to step 9
T=(T+M)= 1 3 6 10 15 21 28 basically T is a series where next is added as 2,3,4,5,6,7 to prev number   2 3 4  5  6  7 if one look from other angle

Comment: Maybe you want to break your answer up into a few sentences here? I think your answer is correct but it's very hard to understand. You could also go step by step through the code to show what it does at each step